# jQuery change nested html elements

Tags: jquery

I have a wrong generated piece of html code:

```
<h1 class="title">Some Value
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <a href="#">link2</a>
    <a href="#">link3</a>
    <a href="#">link4</a>
</h1>
```

How can I change this with jQuery at runtime that will be like this:

```
<h1 class="title">Some Value</h1>
<p>
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <a href="#">link2</a>
    <a href="#">link3</a>
    <a href="#">link4</a>
</p>
```

P.S. There can be any number of links within the h1 element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.title').after($('<p>').append($('.title').children())).html($('.title').text().trim());
```

Edit: If you have multiple <h1> elements, you can loop through them:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.title').each(function() {
    $(this).after($('<p>').append($(this).children())).html($(this).text().trim());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="title">Some Value
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <a href="#">link2</a>
    <a href="#">link3</a>
    <a href="#">link4</a>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if every `h1` element will have the `'title'` class so I implemented for every instance of h1.

```
$("h1").each(function() {
    var innerhtml = "<p>";
    $(this).find("a").each(function() {
        innerhtml += $(this).html();
    });
    innerhtml += "</p>";
    $(this).html(innerhtml);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to your html

```
<h1 class="title">Some Value
    <a href="#">link 1</a>
    <a href="#">link 2</a>
    <a href="#">link 3</a>
    <a href="#">link 4</a>
</h1>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var links = $('h1.title a');
    $('h1.title').after('<p class="movehere"></p>');
    $('p.movehere').append(links);
    $('h1.title a').remove();
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpjbpM